# Cannot edit a User record using Rails Admin. Email is already taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-admin

What would cause me not to be able to edit a `User` record using Rails Admin?

I can edit every other record fine, but when I try to edit this particular record I get this error:

```
User failed to be updated
- Email has already been taken
```

I'm using Devise for user signups, along with this model validation:

```
validates :email,     uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

I go to the user edit form in Rails Admin, change some other field and on submit get the error above. It's really strange and I'm trying to see if there may be any ideas I may have missed.

Why would this validation trigger when I'm just updating the record? There is only one record with that particular email value, and that's the one I'm editing.

Comment: Validations always trigger when you do `save` or `create` or `update_attributes` ... are you sure you haven't got another record with the same email but with different case?  Is it possible the email validation was added later in the project, or maybe you saved with `validate: false` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try limiting your validation to create and see whether that makes a difference.

```
validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, on: :create
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for validating email is right.

You got the default validation message "**Email has already been taken**", because you have the **same** email in your **Users Table**.

It's either part of a seed file so you don't remember saving it.
Or has been saved by other user.

Please try to search it, like:

```
User.find_by(:email => "test_mail_here")
# so you can check duplication ef email.
```

The default validation of your code is for: **create & update**

You can use :

```
validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, on: :create
```

But, I think much better **NOT** to used it.

Best solution for me, is update or delete the duplicate email. So you can use the full functionality of **validates** method again.